# What does POST / mean?

Tags: asp.net, iis

This is driving me up a wall.

For whatever reason, I sometimes find in my IIS log that a user requested a page, such as Application.aspx

So I see in IIS Log   GET /Application.aspx

However, every now and then and for some obscure reason, the user will fill out the form and do

POST /

Has anyone experienced this?

I am using IIS 8 on Server 2012, with Standard W3C logging enabled.

Googling "POST /" is proving useless.

Comment: `POST` indicates that a user *submitted a form* or sent some other *bulk data* to your server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest And also http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get

Comment: If it data/a page is being requested with data being sent along (such as from a form), chances are it will use a [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

All `POST /` means is that the browser sent a `POST` request to the root of your site.

If none of your pages do this, then it is probably a bot.

Comment: I was able to confirm it was a live user from a Windows 7 Computer using Chrome as the navigator.  What baffles me is that they pull up my form, and then when they go to submit it, I randomly and sparsely seem to get a postback of POST /    which is an attempt to post to the root, instead of posting back to my Application.aspx page.  This I do not understand   :(     IIS 8 Bug????

Comment: @AjaxNgnurse How did you determine that? The user agent? That can be spoofed.

Comment: User Agent + complain from my internal department that an application was submitted but never made it to their screen.  Note that I've seen this happen very few times.  We get hundreds such submits in a month and they all show up as POST /Application.aspx